# iOSアプリ swift UIWebViewでYoutubeを埋め込み再生する際にDNSサーバーを変更

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, dns, youtube-player-api

swift2にてYoutube再生アプリを作っています。
UIWebViewでYoutubeを埋め込み再生しているのですが、動画によっては
「特定のサイトでの再生が制限されています」
が表示され、再生することができません。

そこで、再生する際にDNSサーバーを変更すれば再生できるのではないかと予想しています。
いろいろググってみると
「youtube-ui.l.google.com」
というものがヒットしました。
これはDNSサーバーの名前？なのでしょうか。

サーバー等の知識に乏しく解決することができません。

swiftのUIWebViewで
[https://www.youtube.com/embed/動画ID](https://www.youtube.com/embed/%E5%8B%95%E7%94%BBID)
を再生する際に、YouTubeからアクセスしているかのようにDNSサーバーを変更するにはどのように実装すればよいでしょうか。

ご教授願います。

現在は
let youtubeURL = "[https://www.youtube.com/embed/動画ID](https://www.youtube.com/embed/%E5%8B%95%E7%94%BBID)"
let url = NSURL(string : youtubeURL)
let urlRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)
self.PlayerWebView.loadRequest(urlRequest)
と、実装しています。

追記2015.03.17
直接HTMLを読み込むようにしたら解決しました。

Comment: 「DNSを変更すれば再生できる」というセオリーを検証するのが先決でしょう。Youtoubeで見ているのか埋め込みで見ているのかはクライアント側の話なので、DNSでは解決しないのでは？

Answer (score 1):

以下の情報によると、そのエラーは収益化対象の動画なのでYoutubeで見てくださいという意味でDNSの設定は関係ないようです。

https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/youtube-ja/9Qph7xdqs_c